# What is best way to get count on spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is best way to get count on spark Dataframe?

1) I have tried count which will add one action. but I don't want to add additional action.

2) I have used accumulator on RDD, to do that dataframe needs to convert into RDD and even accumulator is not accurate.

I am wondering spark is mature enough and it does not have any other way. I think there must be some way to get count without impacting performance/runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no other way apart from accumulator without adding action. To use accumulator need to convert into rdd.